# Automatically run extension code in Visual Studio on startup

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

Can I create an extension for Visual Studio that runs in the background as soon as the user opens the Visual Studio IDE? For example, I am building an extension that gets the current active file address in Visual Studio (with C#), but I would like this extension to always run in the background without having to be activated by the user clicking a button or pressing some key combination.

Is this possible, and if so, what is the best way of doing it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Regards, Erfan

Comment: Depending upon what you're trying to do, you can specify your extension to load for certain file types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you tagged your question with `visual-studio-2010` I assume you are working on an "Add-in" rather than a "VSPackage Extensions".

In this case, you can use the `OnConnection` event handler.

If you are working on a VSPackage Extensions, you can use the attribute `ProvideAutoLoad`.

Just search for these, you will find sufficient information. Both ways are also described shortly [here under "How can I run my add-in code in a VSPackage?"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn246938.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

For VS 2010 and higher the recommended extensibility approach is a package (VS 2015 won't allow add-ins).

To get the package loaded when Visual Studio is loaded see [HOWTO: Autoload a Visual Studio package](https://web.archive.org/web/20201021212003/http://www.mztools.com/articles/2013/MZ2013027.aspx).

Once loaded, your package may be interested in two different kind of selection change events:

- To get notified when the selection in the Solution Explorer changes, get the [IVsMonitorSelection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsmonitorselection.aspx) interface and call the [AdviseSelectionEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsmonitorselection.adviseselectionevents.aspx)/UnadviseSelectionEvents and provide a class that implements the [IVsSelectionEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsselectionevents.aspx) interface.
- To get notified when the active window changes (which can be a document window or a toolwindow), implement the [IVsWindowFrameNotify](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivswindowframenotify.aspx) interface.

Answer (score 4):

For Extension add following attribute to Package class, this will load the extension when a solution is not open in visual studio. I have tested this with VS 2015 and 2017.

```
[ProvideAutoLoad(UIContextGuids80.NoSolution)]
```